# Display completion options from top to bottom in alphabetical order?

Tags: completion, sorting

Completion are currently listed in alphabetical order as

```
a b c
d e f
```

With alphabetical order going from left to right.
How can I can change this to.

```
a c e
b d f
```

With alphabetical order going from top to bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is described at the end of the [Completion options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Options.html) section in the Emacs manual.

To get vertical ordering, just set `completions-format` to `vertical` by either setting it via the customize interface, or by adding

```lisp
(setq completions-format 'vertical)
```

to your init file (and reload).

You can also customize this option with
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `completions-format` <kbd>RET</kbd>
or with the help of the `Options` menu under `Customize Emacs` -> `Specific Option...`.